Chain rule in Sobolev space $p=\infty$
I need to prove the chain rule for Sobolev spaces. I managed to prove it for $p< \infty$ using the density of $W^{1,p}\cap\mathcal{C}^\infty$ in $W^{1,p}$, but I struggle with the case $p=\infty$. I know that similar questions have been asked already (for example 1 and 2) but they all use the fact that $W^{1,\infty}$ is just the space of Lipschitz functions, however this is something that we have not done in class. I was wondering if there's a way to prove it without knowing the property above? Or does the property have a possibly easy proof?
Edit: Maybe I should have specified a bit what I mean. Let $F$ be a $\mathcal{C}^1_b$-diffeomorphism and $u$ the function of our Sobolev space: what I want to show is $\frac{d}{dx_j}(u\circ F)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac{d}{dy_i}u\circ F \frac{d}{dx_j}F_i$

Can you specify what you mean by "chain rule"?

@gerw yes, i edited the post now

If you already managed to show the chain rule for $p < \infty$, you already now that $u \circ F$ is weakly differentiable, since $u \in W^{1,p}$. And since $u \in W^{1,\infty}$, the weak derivative of $u \circ F$ is bounded. Do I miss something?

@gerw so in the case that i struggle with $u \in W^{1, \infty}$ and it’s separate from the case $p< \infty$. what i mean is, $u$ need not be in $W ^{1,p}$ for $p< \infty$. but you might be right and i just don’t know/see the connection between sobolev spaces for different values $p$?

What is your domain? $\mathbb{R}^n$ or a bounded set?

I just want to add here if anyone is ever reding this, I got a really useful hint: if $u \in W^{1,\infty}$ we have $u \in W^{1,1}_{loc}$
